# How to check key in Firebase-DataBase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I do a check this way

```
If(reference.child(userId).getKey() == null){ //... }
```

And get false, but I don't have the key, I don't know what to do.

My DataBase:

[image]

The user key is `userId = zhdl21dsa...`

Comment: the key will never be null

Comment: @BasilBattikhi The key is UserId

Comment: So do you have the key and you want to check if it is exist? 
or the firebase doen't have they key and you want to check ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I have a key and I want to know if it is in FireBase

Comment: okay what is the problem with your code then ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi he checks that the key is there, but it does not exist

Comment: I don't know what is the problem with your code but you can make a work around, add a listener to that key if you get an exception then the user doesn't exist otherwise it exist

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Could you show a small example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a single value event listener in order to check if the user exist or not

```
DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference users = reference.child("users");
users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.child("zhdl21dsa").exists()) {
                // run some code
            }else{

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```